# How to read Nfc tags in android?

Tags: android, nfc

How can i read and display the NDEF messages from NFC tags? Please help me.  Can anyone provide the sample source code to read the Nfc tag?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) The general description of the NFC on android is [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html)
2) The NFCDemo is [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NFCDemo/index.html)
3) Very good information are also [here](http://www.jessechen.net/blog/how-to-nfc-on-the-android-platform/)
4) Also the book "Programming Android" from "Zigurd Mednieks" has a chapter about the NFC

BR
STeN

Comment: Unfortunately, NFCDemo no longer available at that link.

Answer (score 6):

We have two option to read the nfc card.

1. Read from cache

   ```
      Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
       if (ndef == null) {
           // NDEF is not supported by this Tag. 
           return null;
       }

       NdefMessage ndefMessage = ndef.getCachedNdefMessage();

       if (ndefMessage == null) {
           mTextView.setText("The tag is empty !");
           return null;
       }

       NdefRecord[] records = ndefMessage.getRecords();
       for (NdefRecord ndefRecord : records) {
           if (ndefRecord.getTnf() == NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN && Arrays.equals(ndefRecord.getType(), NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT)) {
               try {
                   return readText(ndefRecord);
               } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                   Log.e(TAG, "Unsupported Encoding", e);
               }
           }
       }
   ```
2. Read directly by using

```
public void readFromTag(Intent intent){

    Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(detectedTag);


    try{
        ndef.connect();

        txtType.setText(ndef.getType().toString());
        txtSize.setText(String.valueOf(ndef.getMaxSize()));
        txtWrite.setText(ndef.isWritable() ? "True" : "False");
        Parcelable[] messages = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);

        if (messages != null) {
            NdefMessage[] ndefMessages = new NdefMessage[messages.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                ndefMessages[i] = (NdefMessage) messages[i];
            }
            NdefRecord record = ndefMessages[0].getRecords()[0];

            byte[] payload = record.getPayload();
            String text = new String(payload);
            txtRead.setText(text);


            ndef.close();

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Read From Tag.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure the **AndroidManifest.xml** file contains the use-permision, intent-filter and meta-data for the NFC, it should look like this.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mynfcreader">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyNFCReader">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_filter" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

2. Create the xml file **nfc_filter.xml** referenced in the above manifest file, at the res/xml folder, create the xml folder if it is not yet there, the content should contain the following.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
        <!-- class name -->
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

3. **activity_main.xml** the layout file with a TextView for displaying the message read from NFC tag.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nfc_contents"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:padding="32dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

4. The **MainActivity.kt** with the code for reading message from NFC tag and displaying it to the screen.

```kotlin
package com.example.mynfcreader

import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.nfc.NdefMessage
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter
import android.nfc.Tag
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Parcelable
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.mynfcreader.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException
import java.nio.charset.Charset
import kotlin.experimental.and

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var tvNFCContent: TextView
    private lateinit var nfcAdapter: NfcAdapter
    private lateinit var pendingIntent: PendingIntent
    var myTag: Tag? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        tvNFCContent = binding.nfcContents
        tvNFCContent.text = "Place the back of the phone over a NFC tag to read message from NFC tag"

        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)
        if (nfcAdapter == null) {
            // Stop here, we definitely need NFC
            Toast.makeText(this, "This device doesn't support NFC.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            finish()
        }

        readFromIntent(intent)

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0,
            Intent(this, javaClass).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
            0
        )
        val tagDetected = IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)
        tagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        readFromIntent(intent)
    }

    private fun readFromIntent(intent: Intent) {
        val action = intent.action
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED == action || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED == action || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED == action) {
            myTag = intent.getParcelableExtra<Parcelable>(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG) as Tag?
            val rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES)
            var msgs = mutableListOf<NdefMessage>()
            if (rawMsgs != null) {
                for (i in rawMsgs.indices) {
                    msgs.add(i, rawMsgs[i] as NdefMessage)
                }
                buildTagViews(msgs.toTypedArray())
            }
        }
    }

    private fun buildTagViews(msgs: Array<NdefMessage>) {
        if (msgs == null || msgs.isEmpty()) return
        var text = ""
        val payload = msgs[0].records[0].payload
        val textEncoding: Charset = if ((payload[0] and 128.toByte()).toInt() == 0) Charsets.UTF_8 else Charsets.UTF_16 // Get the Text Encoding
        val languageCodeLength: Int = (payload[0] and 51).toInt() // Get the Language Code, e.g. "en"
        try {
            // Get the Text
            text = String(
                payload,
                languageCodeLength + 1,
                payload.size - languageCodeLength - 1,
                textEncoding
            )
        } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
            Log.e("UnsupportedEncoding", e.toString())
        }
        tvNFCContent.text = "Message read from NFC Tag:\n $text"
    }
}
```

5. Install the app on an Android phone, and place the back of the android phone over a NFC tag, the app will be launched and displays message on the screen if the NFC tag has any messages stored on it.